# what's the difference between std::codecvt and std::codecvt_utf8

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

there is a question makes me feel confused. What the exactly difference between std::codecvt and std::codecvt_utf8? As the STL reference saying, std::codecvt_utf8 is a drived class from std::codecvt, but could you please tell me why this function would throw an exception?

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>> cvtUtf8 { new std::codecvt_byname<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>(".65001") };
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> cvt_utf8;

std::string strUtf8 = cvt_utf8.to_bytes(L"你好");
std::string strUtf8Failed = cvtUtf8.to_bytes(L"你好"); // throw out an exception. bad conversion
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`codecvt` is a template intended to be used as a base of a conversion facet for converting strings between different encodings and different sizes of code units. It has a protected destructor, which practically prevents it from being used without inheritance.

`codecvt<wchar_t, char, mbstate_t>` specialization in particular is a conversion facet for *"conversion between the system's native wide and the single-byte narrow character sets"*.

`codecvt_utf8` inherits `codecvt` and is facet is for conversion between *"UTF-8 encoded byte string and UCS2 or UCS4 character string"*. It has a public destructor.

If the system native wide encoding is not UCS2 or UCS4 or if system native narrow encoding isn't UTF-8, then they do different things.

---

> could you please tell me why this function would throw an exception?

Probably because the C++ source file was not encoded in the same encoding as the converter expects the input to be.

---

> ```
> new std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>(".65001")
> ```

`codecvt` has no constructor that accepts a string.

---

It might be worth noting that `codecvt` and `wstring_convert` have been deprecated since C++17.

> which one is the instead of codecvt?

The standard committee chose to deprecate `codecvt` before providing an alternative. You can either keep using it - with the knowledge that it may be replaced by something else in future, and with the knowledge that it has serious shortcomings that are cause for deprecation - or you can do what you could do prior to C++11: implement the conversion yourself, or use a third party implementation.

Comment: There is an implicit conversion when we send a string to codecvt. The codecvt accepts _Locinfo, and _Locinfo accepts const char*.  One more question: "codecvt has been deprecated since C++17", which one is the instead  of codecvt?

Comment: @P.Wang there is no such consturctor, nor such type in standard library as `_Locinfo`. If you use non-standard extensions, you should mention it in the question.

Comment: @P.Wang I expanded the answer with your question.

Comment: Uh... I know that cppreference.com talks about UCS-2, but... are you *really sure* that is what they meant? Not UTF-16? The two are not identical, and the differences  (surrogate pairs for non-BMP code points in UTF-16, UCS-2 being limited to the BMP) can be **really** important... (As opposed to UCS-4 and UTF-32, which *are* identical for all practical purposes.)

Comment: @DevSolar I did indeed quote cppreference verbatim (should probably have cited). I checked the standard now, and it says UCS-2 specifcally, so cppreference appears to be accurate. At least I hope that the *standard* means what it says.

Comment: Sheesh... and there I was, hoping (for clarity's sake) that they had taken UCS-2 quietly out the back door and beaten to death by now... :-\ Thanks for the lookup.

Comment: @DevSolar well, it existed and was used, so somebody may need to convert it still. There's (now deprecated of course) `codecvt_utf8_utf16` for UTF-16 conversion.

Comment: I am aware that UCS-2 is (or was) at the heart of most of Microsoft's "Unicode" functionality. That's why I am holding a grudge; because MS was never really clear in their documentation, wildly mixing "UCS-2", "Unicode", and "UTF-16" as if it were all the same thing. :-\

Comment: @DevSolar Exactly! MS mixed UCS-2 and UTF-16, so the codecvt_utf8 of MS' STL really means UCS-2. All of MS applications are in used of USC-2.

Comment: @user2079303 The std::codecvt got an override constructor function in the STL of Visual Studio. It's the same to std::codecvt_byname.